# Using variables from two different while loops

Tags: java, variables, loops, while-loop, scoping

How do I use variables from different while loops and insert them in a print statement?

```
 public class Squares{
   public static void main (String [] args){
      int counterA = 0;
      int counterB= 0;

      while (counterA<51){
           counterA++;
           if (counterA % 5 == 0){
                int one = (counterA*counterA);
           }               
      }
      while (counterB<101){
           counterB++;
           if (counterB % 2 == 0){
                int two = (counterB*counterB);         
           }    
      }
       System.out.println(one+two);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I only get one line when I should be getting several

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Post your problem statement?

Comment: Your print statement will only be executed once. Consider moving it inside a loop.

Comment: If you want multiple lines, you need to put your println call inside a loop.

Comment: Please make the problem statement more clearer...

Comment: I'm trying to print the squares of the numbers from 1-50 that are evenly divisble by 5 and the squares of the numbers from 1-100 that are evenly divisible by 2 but in ONE print statement.

Comment: Patricia Shanahan, make the println inside WHICH loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare the local variables one and two outside the loops

```
public class Squares{
   public static void main (String [] args){
      int counterA = 0;
      int counterB= 0;
      int one=0;
      int two=0;  

      while (counterA<51){
           counterA++;
           if (counterA % 5 == 0){
                one = (counterA*counterA);
           }               
      }
      while (counterB<101){
           counterB++;
           if (counterB % 2 == 0){
                two = (counterB*counterB);         
           }    
      }
       System.out.println(one+two);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your answer

```
public class Squares{
 public static void main (String [] args){
  int counterA = 0;
  int counterB= 0;

  while (counterA<101){
       counterA++;
       int one,two;
       if (counterA % 5 == 0){
            one = (counterA*counterA);
       }               
        if (counterA % 2 == 0){
            two = counterA * counterA;
        }
        System.out.println(ont + two);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variables outside your loop, and assign them the values inside the loop!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite broad, as there are many ways to do this. You just need to collect the results from within the loops into a global variable. If you want to specifically make a string, then you can use something like a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Here is an example with no spacing between numbers:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int counterA = 0;
int counterB = 0;

while (counterA < 51) {
  counterA++;
  if (counterA % 5 == 0){
    sb.append(counterA * counterA);
  }               
}
while (counterB<101) {
  counterB++;
  if (counterB % 2 == 0) {
    sb.append(counterB * counterB);         
  }    
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

You can also put the variables into arrays, etc:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (counterA < 51) {
  counterA++;
  if (counterA % 5 == 0){
    list.add(counterA * counterA);
  }               
}
```